# Why does iOS 8 hate my AutoLayout but iOS 9 loves it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am initialising a view `infoScreen` and adding it as a subview of the screen with its bottom, left and right constraints set like this:

```
let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoScreen, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoScreen, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .RightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
if (point.y < halfOfScreen) {
    yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoScreen, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: highlightedView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: radius + stalkLength)
}
else {
    // This gets called the first time round.
    yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoScreen, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: highlightedView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -radius - stalkLength)
}

view.addConstraints([left, right, yConstraint])
```

as well as it's height being set.

Then after a button within `infoScreen` is clicked, I'm calling `infoScreen.removeFromSuperview()`.

Then the same function is used to reinitialise `infoScreen` with different parameters, and add it to the screen. However, this time it has its top constraint set instead of the bottom constraint.

In iOS 9 this works perfectly, however in iOS 8, it acts as if the bottom constraint is still set and messes up the view. If I run the code so that it never has the bottom constraint set (essentially skipping over the first run of the initialisation function), then it works fine in iOS 8. What could be causing this?

Comment: Apple fixed a bug in iOS 9?

Comment: @onnoweb possibly, but how can I get round that bug? :/

Comment: Can you try to remove the yConstraint only, instead of removing infoScreen from its superview ? And then call a function that sets this yConstraint only ?

Comment: ( `view.removeConstraint(yConstraint)` )

Comment: yConstraint has to be defined outside of your method, though. So it can be accessible from any methods of your class.

Comment: See if this works, 
- "removeConstraint" method, 
- set up constraints and, 
- "updateConstraints" method.

Comment: @Randy tried it and it didn't work! Does the exact same thing.

Comment: @stuti that didn't work either :(